# Refactorting if-else blocks into more concise code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a bunch of `if-elsif` blocks like this that end in a else statement so my structure looks like this:

```
if path.end_with?('something')
   template_name = 'something.json.erb'
   res.body =  ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path("../#{template_name}",  __FILE__))).result(binding)
   res.status = 200
   res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
elsif path.end_with?('somethingELSE')
   template_name = 'somethingELSE.json.erb'
   res.body =  ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path("../#{template_name}",  __FILE__))).result(binding)
   res.status = 200
   res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
# a couple more similar if-elsif  blocks in here
else
  res.status = 400
  res['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
  res.body = "Invalid path"
```

So there is a lot of repeated code in the section that has blocks of if-elsif that are just repeared. Basically just the line that sets the template_name is necessary and we should be able to factore out the rest of those next three lines but then I have that else at the end that prevents me from doing that.

How would you suggest to refactor this code to be more concise and less repeated code in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
['something', 'somethingELSE', 'somethingAGAIN'].each DO  |match|
  substitute = match if path.end.with?(match)
end
if substitute
   template_name = "#{substitute}.json.erb"
   res.body =  ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path("../#{template_name}",  __FILE__))).result(binding)
   res.status = 200
   res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
 else
   res.status = 400
  res['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
  res.body = "Invalid path"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way to do it.

```
if path.end_with?('something') || path.end_with?('somethingELSE')
    if path.end_with?('something')
       template_name = 'something.json.erb'
    elsif path.end_with?('somethingELSE')
       template_name = 'somethingELSE.json.erb'
    # a couple more similar if-elsif  blocks in here
    end

   res.body =  ERB.new(File.read(File.expand_path("../#{template_name}",  __FILE__))).result(binding)
   res.status = 200
   res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
else
  res.status = 400
  res['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
  res.body = "Invalid path"
end
```

You could probably also parse the `something` and `somethingELSE` off of your path to get the template name, simplifying this even further.

Assuming you've got a proper path, `a/path/to/something` you could do:

```
template_name = "/assuming/this/is/a/path".split('/').last + '.json.erb'
```

But I can't say without seeing your other conditionals.